# No "Huge APP partition scheme" (ESP32)

Tags: esp32, partition

I recently downloaded the expressif ESP32 library and I'm trying to run the CameraWebServer example. Attempting to compile it results in the following error:

```
Sketch uses 2529577 bytes (192%) of program storage space. Maximum is 1310720 bytes.
Sketch too big; see http://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/Troubleshooting#size for tips on reducing it.
```

I can reduce this number (192%) to 120% by changing partition scheme from "Default" to "No OTA (Large APP)". Online I've seen people using a partition scheme called "Huge APP", which I believe would solve my problem, but I don't see that option in Tools. Only "Default", "Large App" and "Minimal SPIFFS" (which doesn't work either).

How can I get the "Huge APP" partition scheme option in Arduino IDE?

Comment: Did the people online tell what core they are using for their ESP32? Also the used board is important. I use the esp32 core by Espressif Systems and I cannot see such a partition scheme for the Wemos Lolin32, but the ESP32 Dev Module shows more partition options up to 3MB for the app.

Comment: I do see the option if I switch the board the ESP32 Dev Module and it compiles successfully! My teacher told me to use the Wemos Lolin32 board, so will it work fine if I change the board to Dev Module?

Comment: It's possible to manually edit the board definition (*boards.txt*) to add a "Huge" partition scheme, if there'e enough storage space available. You can look up the syntax of the board definitions and add `huge_app.upload.maximum_size=3145728` (or more, if there's space available) and its associated entries as a new partition scheme under the board entry for your ESP32Cam.

Comment: Thank you so much, I found the file and added the partition scheme and it looks like it's working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to fix the issue by editing the boards.txt file and adding the following lines:

```
lolin32.menu.PartitionScheme.huge_app=Huge APP (3MB No OTA/1MB SPIFFS)
lolin32.menu.PartitionScheme.huge_app.build.partitions=huge_app
lolin32.menu.PartitionScheme.huge_app.upload.maximum_size=3145728
```

This will add a "Huge APP" partition scheme to WEMOS Lolin32.

Comment: Exactly, this is what I described in my comment. Make sure you have a copy or backup of the altered *boards.txt* files as it will be overwritten when you update the ESP32 Board Manager.